# Find frequencies of all factor combinations of all column combinations

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with n variables whose values are all factors. Now I would like to select m columns from this dataframe (m < n) and find the frequencies of all factor combinations of all possible columns selected.

I have looked up but I only found how to find frequencies of factor combinations if specific columns are chose. In my case, there could be many combinations of columns since m < n

Here is our data, all variable have factor values.

```r
company <- data.frame("country" = c("USA", "China", 'France', "Germany"),
                    "category" = c("C-corp", "S-corp", "C-corp", "LLC"),
                    "Type" = c("Public", "Private", "Private", "Private"),
                    "Profit" = c("High", "High", "High", "Low"))
```

Now I want to select 2 columns (m = 2) and find out about the frequency of factor combinations of all of the possible variables selected

In this case, I can have "country = USA & category = S-Corp", "country = USA & category = C-Corp", "country = China & category = LLC". But I could also select other columns and have "country = USA & Profit = Low", "country = China & Type = Public". I want to know the frequeies of all of these combinations

Edit: My expected output is something like

```r
country = USA, category = C-corp  freq 1
country = USA, category = S-corp  freq 0
country = USA, category = LLC  freq 0
country = China, category = LLC  freq 0
country = France, category = C-corp  freq 1
country = USA, type = Public    freq 1
country = China, type = Public    freq 0
Type = Private, Profit = High   freq 2
Type = Public, category = LLC  freq 0
category = Private, Profit = Low freq 1
```

If I need to select 2 columns, I need all the possible column combinations, orders don't matter

Answer (score 1):

The combinations part sounds like `expand.grid()`:

```
expand.grid(company[, 1:2])

   country category
1      USA   C-corp
2    China   C-corp
3   France   C-corp
4  Germany   C-corp
5      USA   S-corp
6    China   S-corp
7   France   S-corp
8  Germany   S-corp
9      USA   C-corp
10   China   C-corp
11  France   C-corp
12 Germany   C-corp
13     USA      LLC
14   China      LLC
15  France      LLC
16 Germany      LLC

# or if you want 4 columns with all countries, do a cross join:

merge(company[, 1, drop = F], company[, -1], by = NULL)

#or if you want 4 columns with all possible results, do expand.grid without subsetting:

expand.grid(company)
```

The second part sounds like `table()`. You can perform it directly on the `company` data.frame:

```
table(company)

, , Type = Private, Profit = High

         category
country   C-corp LLC S-corp
  China        0   0      1
  France       1   0      0
  Germany      0   0      0
  USA          0   0      0

, , Type = Public, Profit = High

         category
country   C-corp LLC S-corp
  China        0   0      0
  France       0   0      0
  Germany      0   0      0
  USA          1   0      0

, , Type = Private, Profit = Low

         category
country   C-corp LLC S-corp
  China        0   0      0
  France       0   0      0
  Germany      0   1      0
  USA          0   0      0

, , Type = Public, Profit = Low

         category
country   C-corp LLC S-corp
  China        0   0      0
  France       0   0      0
  Germany      0   0      0
  USA          0   0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a nested loop of the table function:

```
for (j in 1:ncol(company)) {
    for (i in 1:ncol(company)) {
          print(table(company[[j]],
                      company[[i]]))
      }
}
```

It's ugly and has a lot of duplicates, but it's quick and easy for your purposes.

Comment: Perhaps the inner loop only needs to go to j? for (i in 1:j) ... ?